# What does the Ankh do?

Tags: paranautical-activity

I've found this powerup item a few times now.  The "Ankh".  Whenever I use it though, I don't notice any changes, and can't figure out what it does.  What does it do?

[image: Ankh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ankh gives you invulnerability to all damage for the duration of the effect.

Comment: Wow, seriously?  I guess I should stop wasting them then...